# Is this an Acceptable Site to ask about Linguistics?

Tags: discussion

I am wondering whether English Language & Usage is an acceptable place to discuss topics of linguistics.

- Corpus linguistics questions (e.g. "Is the English conformity with Zipf's Law unique or universal?")
- "How would a person with a native language of Han Chinese likely construct the sentence 'I went to the store to buy some milk?' if they were speaking in English?"

etc.

Comment: You can ask about linguistics as they pertain to English, but you might get better results at [linguistics.se].

Comment: Oh, of course. I should have guessed there'd be one of those. Thanks!